# How to import HTML Outlook mails into MS Access using VBA

Tags: html, sql-server, ms-access

I have been searching the internet for hours to find a solution to my question.

I know how to import mails for a long time, but can't keep the format of the HTML-body like I could do when copy the body from OL by hand into the Rich-text memo field on an access form.

The field (olbody) is bound to a SQL server table field olbody (nvarchar(max)) and could store html mail body text when I insert the content of the clipboard.

I even tried to read the .HTMLbody property in the clipboard

```
clp.SetText .HTMLBody
clp.PutInClipboard
```

and then I pasted manually the content of the clipboard with Ctrl+V in the field, but again, it does no show up like the HTML mail. But I can see all HTML commands, which should format the mail.

Without formating the mail in the access field, the content is almost unreadable because no tab, lineskip etc. is in the body.

Any help welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to display HTML is using a web browser. This means: use the web browser control!

You can load the HTML in the webbrowser control on load, and when your mail field changes.

Example code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim wb As Object
    Set wb = MyWebbrowserControl.Object
    With wb
        .Navigate2 "about:blank"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4 '=READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            'This is a somewhat inefficient way to wait, but loading a blank page should only take a couple of milliseconds
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.Open
        .Document.Write MemoField.Value
        .Document.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Replace Memofield with your mail field, and MyWebbroserControl with your webbrowser control, and you should be ready to go.

Note that you probably should use the Access web browser, and not the ActiveX web browser. This code will work with both, but the Access web browser control uses a more modern version of IE, and doesn't come with a non-removable border.

Comment: Erik, thanks a lot, it works. But playing around I found another solution. I sticked to the solution with the clipboard but did not paste it with Ctrl+V but by code clipboard.GetFromClipboard
Me.olBody = clipboard.GetText.
The linespacing, tabs, everything shows in the memo-field like in the mail, execpt fonts and font colors. So I combine my sloutin with your webcontrol and get what I want. Thx!

Comment: That's fine, but note that with the full HTML, you can also view things like images, fonts, links, and a lot more content that might be included in some types of mails (such as newsletters). Depending on what kind of mails you're working with, it may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Erik, you are right with images etc. I may display it in the Webbrowser control, but how to save the whole mail WITH images in a table?? Right now every images shows an x, which is in my case sufficient, but is there another way for a proper solution??

Comment: The images are often linked online. If the images are embedded, you're out of luck (unless you save the mail as a file, and then import that file)